# Using the grep filter

Tags: bash, terminal, grep

I have a text file with the name "hello.txt" that contains the following two lines:

```
Hello WORLD!
Hallo world!
```

When I wrote the following

```
grep -i h[ae]llo hello.txt
```

in the terminal, the output was nothing. I expected the print out of the two lines.

Comment: What happens when you enclose the expresion in quotes? `grep -i 'h[ae]llo' hello.txt`

Comment: What `grep` are you using(`grep --version`)? What shell are you using? Are you grepping the correct file?

Comment: @richard I am using bash

Comment: When you entered that grep command, did you get no output then a shell prompt, or did the shell appear to hang, as if awaiting user input? What does this command output: `shopt nullglob`?

Comment: @glennjackman why would nullglob be relevant? The OP might observe this behavior if they have one file named `hallo` and one named `hello` in the pwd, but how would the nullglob option affect it?

Comment: @terdon, if there are no files named hello or hallo, then the pattern does not match and the pattern is removed. The command becomes `grep -i  hello.txt`, so grep is stuck waiting for input on stdin to match the pattern "hello.txt".

Answer (score 2):

It's possible some kind of character set problem is throwing things off for you. Here are some commands you should be able to use to re-create a successful usage of `grep` that may help you.

First let's make a text file in the terminal to avoid any character set problems:

```
echo -e "Hello\nHallo" > foo.txt
```

The `-e` flag tells `echo` we want the `\n` to be interpreted as a newline, and not the literal sequence. This gives us two lines. You should be able to `cat` the file and see it without any issue, like this:

```
cat foo.txt
Hello
Hallo
```

Now you can use the `grep` command you posted before (it doesn't actually need quotes, but you should use them as there are special characters in bash. Also, single quotes not double quotes)

```
grep -i 'h[ae]llo' foo.txt
```

This produces the expected result. If this worked for you, but you are curious as to what is going on with your other text file, you can do a few things to figure out what is going on.

First, try running the `file` command on the file. This should tell you it's a text file, and what encoding it appears to be in.

```
file foo.txt
foo.txt: ASCII text
```

If you get something strange or in a different character encoding, that's going to be a problem. You can also inspect the hexidecimal dump of the file by:

hexdump -C foo.txt

```
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 0a 48 61  6c 6c 6f 0a              |Hello.Hallo.|
0000000c
```

Also as a bonus here is a in-browser Linux emulator you can use that might help you toy around:

http://bellard.org/jslinux/

It even has GCC so you can compile C code!